# Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json in arch linux

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core-3.1, archlinux

I'm having this issue when adding package in my newly created project. The `dotnet restore` command works but the issue persist whenever i install packages from nuget.

Here is the nuget.config:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <configuration>
     <packageSources>
         <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" 
         protocolVersion="3" />
     </packageSources>
   </configuration>
```

And my project file:

```
       <PropertyGroup>
          <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
       </PropertyGroup>

    </Project>
```

This is what i get when i run `dotnet add package MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore`:

```
     Writing /tmp/tmpG0S9pw.tmp
     info : Adding PackageReference for package 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore' into 
     project '/home/silasi/Mywork/c-sharp-projects/aspnetcoreapp/aspnetcoreapp.csproj'.

     info : Restoring packages for /home/silasi/Mywork/c-sharp- 
     projects/aspnetcoreapp/aspnetcoreapp.csproj...

     info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3- 
        flatcontainer/mysql.data.entityframeworkcore/index.json 
               
     info :   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3- 
          flatcontainer/mysql.data.entityframeworkcore/index.json 1166ms

     info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/mysql.data/index.json

     info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3- 
     flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational/index.json

     log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3- 
           flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational/index.json'.

     log  : Name or service not known
     info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3- 
          flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational/index.json

     log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3- 
          flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational/index.json'.

     log  : Name or service not known
     info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3- 
          flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational/index.json

     error: Failed to retrieve information about 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational' 
            from remote source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3- 
            flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational/index.json'.

     error:   Name or service not known
```

NOTE: I'm using Arch Linux.

Comment: Hey @Silasi were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi @phoenix, no, not at all. I just left it as it is. But I'm thinking of doing a fresh install of my system, maybe the problem will go away.

Comment: Thanks @Silasi, I was able to make it work. I have my box behind a proxy and I have set the HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY along with http_proxy and https_proxy (please note both are required as some application require different cases)environment variables in the .bashrc. 

The issue of Name or Service not know is because of the system was behind proxy and when proxy is not set, the host name is not resolved.

Comment: This can be helpful @Phoniex, can you please show me your proxy settings?

Comment: ```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://<host>:<port>
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://<host>:<port>
export http_proxy=http://<host>:<port>
export https_proxy=http://<host>:<port>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Try to reinstall all packages, you can find them by command:
`sudo pacman -Qq | grep -E 'dotnet|standard|aspnet'`

If it doesn't help open folder ~/.nuget/packages and add file nuget.config with code that you can find by this link: [First code snippet](https://zimmergren.net/nuget-error-unable-load-service-index-for-source-unauthorized/)

Hope that it will help someone)